# JavaScript - Converting string variables to math expressions

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to get a button to display the result of a math expression. The problem is that the math expression is stored in a string. This is the code:

```
function bEqu(){
    var test = "2 + 2";
    document.getElementById("numButtons").innerHTML += "<br>" + test;
    //I am trying to get it to return 4.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just *eval* it.

```
document.getElementById("numButtons").innerHTML += "<br>" + eval(test);
```

However, keep it in mind that use `eval` only for simple math calculations and not for *anything* else because eval is **evil**.

Comment: I'll guess that the OP is building a calculator with buttons, so probably building the expression rather than executing arbitrary script.

Comment: @RobG Well, let him post another question on that. As it stands now, my answer answers what OP wants ;)

Comment: Yes, just meant that it's probably fine to use *eval* for this. :-)

Comment: @RobG, sorry for misinterpreting things. I ain't a native English speaker ;)

Comment: That's fine, I didn't say it very well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function bEqu(){
    var test = "2 + 2";
    document.getElementById("numButtons").innerHTML += "<br>" + eval(test);
    //You have returned 4.
    //using eval(test);
}
```

Comment: Give some explanations too with your code, its in `low quality post`.

Comment: ya. I have commented the explanation right? eval() is used to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score -1):

`eval(test)` gives you the proper result `4`.